# How do i Turn ON/OFF the Caps lock key

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

We can able to detect the Caps lock key is ON/OFF using Jquery.
My question is

"can we possible to Turn ON/OFF the Caps lock key using Jquery or Javascript in Keypress event".

And also using C#, How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Nope. Javascript cannot interfere with the OS like that.

Comment: If it can alter with OS then it will be very easy for programmer to make a virus in js which is not possible

Answer (score 4):

You can't change whether the caps lock key is on or off. You can however change whether your input strings are lower or upper case with Javascript based on whether the caps lock key is on or off.

```
for (char in inputString) {
    if(capslock) { // do your caps lock detection here
        if(char === char.toUpperCase()) { // it's upper case
            char = char.toLowerCase();
        } else {
            char = char.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Elliot Bonneville, Thanks for your reply,,,Okay.. can we do this using C#?

Comment: How many situations are there where you can just arbitrarily switch from JS to C#?

Comment: @ManikandanSethuraju: Yes, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962211/programatically-disable-caps-lock

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this jquery like javascript will be sandboxed inside the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,,,Okay.. can we do this using C#?

Comment: Not from the serverside. If you had a client app, yes.

Answer (score 0):

**Detection only:**

```
$('#id').keypress(function(e) { 
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
        alert('caps is on');
    }
});
```

Comment: isn't `s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s` redundant?

Comment: @jbabey: `s.toLowerCase() !== s` would be false for any character that doesn't have case...like, say, punctuation.  Even if `s.toUpperCase() == s` is true.  Course, i'd think it might fail the Turkey Test.

Comment: Where did this code come from, BTW?  It's effectively identical to another now-deleted answer that was posted earlier...

Answer (score 0):

If this would be possible, then I would be able to control user's sound volume, or maybe check what he have in hard disk, I may be more curious and spy his network card traffic...
I would own the world with a simple JavaScript file :)