# How do i Turn OFF the Caps lock key

Tags: c#, wpf

How do i Turn OFF the Caps lock key in textbox. I am using WPF forms.

When textbox is focused I want to turn off caps lock.

Thanks

Comment: even google with 'programmatically turn off caps lock c#' gives first answer in stack overflow.

Comment: Maybe this could help you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534664/how-do-i-turn-on-off-the-caps-lock-key][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534664/how-do-i-turn-on-off-the-caps-lock-key

Comment: @user1811846 Have a heart, at least save the trouble of OP googling it themselves :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962211/programatically-disable-caps-lock

Comment: Do you actually want to turn off the caps lock key, or do you want to enforce a lower case string?

Answer (score 15):

Its easy , Firstly add namespace

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

then declare this in the class

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags,
UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

Finally , at textBox_Enter event add this code

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock)) // Checks Capslock is on
        {
            const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
            const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
            keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
            keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
            (UIntPtr)0);
        }
    }
```

this code will turn off the Capslock .. I have used it at the enter event you can add it according to your requirement!

Checkout this link [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/105103-how-detect-capslock-csharp.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use this code for WPF froms.

```
private void txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.CapsLock) == KeyStates.Toggled) // Checks Capslock is on
        {
            const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
            const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
            keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
            keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
            (UIntPtr)0);
        }

    }
```