# SendKeys.Send Method in WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to send a keystroke (Ctrl + t) for a browser control. But, `SendKeys.Send()` showed an error in a WPF application?

My questions are:

1. Can I use the `SendKeys.Send()` method in a WPF application?
2. Is there any alternative method for sending an automatic keystroke?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SendKeys is part of the System.Windows.Forms Namespace there is not an equivalent method in Wpf. You can not use the SendKeys.Send with WPF but you can use the [SendKeys.SendWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) method, if you add System.Windows.Forms to your project references. Your only other option would be to to PInvoke [SendInput](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendInput).

Be aware that both of these methods send data to the currently active window.

Answer (score 25):

I found a [blog post](http://michlg.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/wpf-send-keys/) describing use of [InputManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputmanager(v=vs.110).aspx). It allows you to simulate keyboard events in WPF.

```
/// <summary>
///   Sends the specified key.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key">The key.</param>
public static void Send(Key key)
{
  if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice != null)
  {
    if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource != null)
    {
      var e = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, key) 
      {
          RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
      };
      InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e);

      // Note: Based on your requirements you may also need to fire events for:
      // RoutedEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyDownEvent
      // RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyUpEvent
      // RoutedEvent = Keyboard.PreviewKeyUpEvent
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great, but is there a way to send some modifiers with the key? (**Ctrl+V** for example?) 

Maybe you can make the KeyboardDevice think the modifier key is pressed somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI this only enqueues the key event in the wpf application itself and can not be used to send keystrokes to other applications.

Comment: FYI- you need to add: 
PresentationCore and WindowsBase via Assembly ref

Comment: I think this example is basically flawed because if it is used while processing a control- or alt-key combination the parameter 'Keyboard.PrimaryDevice' will hand over the currently pressed modifier keys together with the sent key. Say for example you are processing Ctrl-I and want to send a 'Key.Tab' you will end up sending Ctrl-Tab instead. The problem is that .NET doesn't give you access to the modifiers of a KeyboardDevice. There should added a method to access them.