# Can't use SendKeys in WPF application C# VS2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I want to send a simple Enter Key with this command:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

But, I cam't get System.Windows.Forms...the 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace? The application is developed in VS2010 and it is WPF I believe, MainWindow.xaml.cs.

How do I get around it?

Basically, a button in my application will launch an exe and I want to send an 'ENTER' command after that.

Thanks,

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: System.Windows.Forms does not exist

Comment: the type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to have a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll - WPF apps don't reference that by default

Comment: possible duplicate of [SendKeys.Send Method in WPF application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572411/sendkeys-send-method-in-wpf-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll - WPF apps don't reference that by default

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11404560/3090544