# Printing from TEdgeBrowser in Delphi

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, webview2, tedgebrowser

Is there a way to print from the `TEdgeBrowser` implementation in Delphi?

In the older TWebBrowser we used the following code that worked:

```
ControlInterface.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, varIn, varOut);
```

But the `TEdgeBrowser` doesn't seem to support this?

Any thought's greatfully accepted.

Comment: A possible option is to use JavaScript: `EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteScript('window.print();');`.

Comment: Hi thanks that works, just a shame it presents the printing dialog, I need a silent print method as its for a touch screen application where I don't want users to be able to access things but it will do for now, thanks alot.

Comment: I find the whole control flawed. For example, the print dialog is central to the control and not to the screen. The page header / control has lost all fine tweaking like we have in IE printing. And as you say, silent printing. Too many limitations. Also, you can close your app whilst the print dialogue is visible.

Comment: Please see related answer about printing options in WebView2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654738/print-functionality-in-webview2-control/62662770#62662770

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TEdgeBrowser modal print dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77062593/tedgebrowser-modal-print-dialog)

Comment: New abilities to control printing in the control have been added in 2023 by Microsoft. See this question on how to use them with Delphi TEdgeBrowser control: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77062593/101087