# TEdgeBrowser modal print dialog?

Tags: javascript, delphi, tedgebrowser

TEdgeBrowser has [replaced the TWebBrowser](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component).  Is there a way to do a modal dialog print using TEdgeBrowser?  I've tried running Javascript to show the Edge Browser print dialog using this code:

```
EdgeBrowser.ExecuteScript('window.print();');
```

The browser flashes for a second, but there is no print dialog shown.  The TEdgeBrower is also very small in my application, so I'd like to have a modal print dialog if possible.

If I use the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, the print dialog is shown... but is only shown within the small `TEdgeBrowser` window.

Comment: You need to understand one big difference here.  When you try to print something from `TWebBrowser` or Internet Explorer which it encapsulates the OS based Print Dialog is show . Like most standard Dialogs it is shown as modal window. You can observe same print dialog being shown if you try to print something from Notepad that ships with windows.  `TEdgeBrowser` on the other hand does not use OS based print dialog but instead renders its own Print Dialog within its own window. Because of that the print dialog can not be larger than `TEdgeBrowser itself.

Comment: @SilverWarior The newest version of Edge supports printing via a modal dialog shown by the operating system. See my answer on how to use it from Delphi.

Comment: @NineBerry I didn't know about this new functionality before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functionality to control printing in the `Edge WebView control` was [only added within the last months](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes?tabs=dotnetcsharp#10151846) (You need at least version `109.0.1518.46` of Edge and of the Microsoft Edge Runtime installed), so the standard `TEdgeBrowser` component in Delphi does not know it yet.

There is a new method [`ShowPrintUI()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/winrt/microsoft_web_webview2_core/corewebview2?view=webview2-winrt-1.0.1938.49#showprintui) that you can use to specifically open an operating system version of the print dialog that is modal and is shown outside the bounds of the actual browser control.

You can use the new method from Delphi `TEdgeBrowser` by following the steps in [Marcodor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405170/101087) at [WebView2 (TEdgeBrowser) updated Delphi interface (e.g. ICoreWebView2Controller2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66676662/webview2-tedgebrowser-updated-delphi-interface-e-g-icorewebview2controller2).

Using the current WebView2 package from Microsoft, the resultung file `WebView2_TLB.pas` will contain an `ICoreWebView2_16` interface definition which contains among other things the definition for the `ShowPrintUI()` method.

You can then include the `WebView2_TLB.pas` unit into your project and show the system print dialog with this code:

```
var
  WebView: ICoreWebView2_16;
begin
  // Test if browser supports ICoreWebView2_16 interface
  if EdgeBrowser1.DefaultInterface.QueryInterface(ICoreWebView2_16, WebView) = S_OK then
  begin
    // If yes, show system print dialog
    WebView.ShowPrintUI(COREWEBVIEW2_PRINT_DIALOG_KIND_SYSTEM);
  end
  else
  begin
    // Not yet supported, possible fallback?
  end;
end;
```

---

The `ICoreWebView2_16` interface also contains methods for printing the browser content directly to a PDF or to a pre-selected printer without showing a dialog to the user.