# Printing in WinForm through Web

Tags: c#, winforms

My original WinForm auto-print new order from SQL (every 60 seconds)，which I translated into HTML and print it through ((WebBrowser)sender).Print()。

However I am aware that Win 11 no longer support IE browser, does that mean i have to modify my code? (I only use IE for printing purpose because I'm not familiar with winform.reports)

If so, which browser should I preferred? I did some research on CefSharp.WinForms but it doesn't support auto-printing，so i guess Edge is the way to go?

Please include tutorial link/ video with your answer/comment， thank you。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the new `WebView2` control. See winform tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms).

In order to print a page you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654738/print-functionality-in-webview2-control) a simple trick.