# how to Perform Quick Print using Webview2 c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, webview2

In System Webbrowser, there are 2 print functions

- `WebBrowser.Print`  -prints the current document without requiring further user input.
- `WebBrowser.ShowPrintDialog` - Opens the Internet Explorer Print dialog box

With `WebView2`, we can show print preview dialog with the below approach
[Print functionality in WebView2 control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654738/print-functionality-in-webview2-control)

```
await webview2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();");
```

However, I'm not sure how to perform silent printing (without showing print preview).

Thanks

Comment: May be you can grap the content as an image and then print that? https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.capturepreviewasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2-capturepreviewasync(microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2capturepreviewimageformat-system-io-stream)

Comment: if you can help me I want to open the print dialog when I use 
** await webview2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("window.print();"); **
nothing happen at all and when I use 
webview2.CoreWebView2.ShowPrintUI(CoreWebView2PrintDialogKind.System);

it alert me with this message 
Check your printer or select another printer. The printer you chose isn't available or isn't installed correctly.

if you can help me with this I will be happey

Answer (score 0):

This is the GitHub issue for the silent printing feature:

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1331

A comment from Oct. 6/22 says it's been added as an experimental feature in v1.0.1414:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes?tabs=dotnetcsharp#experimental-features