# Is there a way to print a pdf in C# net 6?

Tags: .net, printing, c#-10.0, pdfdocument

I want to send a pdf file to a printer programmatically and I'm wondering if  there is  a way of printing a file (send for example a pdf to a printer ) using .net standard libraries  (PrintDowument class) or an open source one with MIT license?
Thanks

I tried this

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ();
info.Verb = "print";
info.Arguments = "\"" +printerName + "\"";
info.FileName = pdfFilePath;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.UseShellExecute = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

using Process p = new ();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();
p.WaitForInputIdle();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
if (!p.HasExited)
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

here I have to specify which process to use (Adobe or another) but what I want is to take a pdf and send it to a specified printer without calling an external process.

Comment: Why do you use Process class where you can use System.Printing ?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is [CoreWebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/). It is the same component used by Microsoft Edge for showing content - including PDF documents. Since this is a graphical user control, it only really makes sense for use in client facing applications (WinUI, WPF, Winforms, etc.) where you want to print documents from a document preview. It was not designed for a service even though you may be able to get it to work. (I haven't tried.)

Check these two methods:

- [CoreWebView2.PrintAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.printasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1823.32#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2-printasync) - To print with no user interaction.
- [CoreWebView2.ShowPrintUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.showprintui?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1823.32#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2-showprintui(microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2printdialogkind)) - To print using a dialog box with user interaction.

Here's an overview of [three methods for printing from the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654738/print-functionality-in-webview2-control).

Also, a hint for getting started is to make sure to use the [CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.corewebview2initializationcompleted) event to initialize the control or you'll run into errors related to null values while setting properties. This is a rough template for getting started. I used this with a C# Winforms application in .Net6:

```
private static Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment _webView2Environment;
private Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Deferral _webView2Deferral;
private Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs _webView2Args;

public PanelDocumentViewer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void PanelDocumentViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webView2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += CoreWebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
    webView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(_webView2Environment);
}

private void CoreWebView2_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webView2.CoreWebView2.Settings.HiddenPdfToolbarItems =
        CoreWebView2PdfToolbarItems.Search
        | CoreWebView2PdfToolbarItems.Save
        | CoreWebView2PdfToolbarItems.SaveAs;

    if (_webView2Deferral != null)
    {
        _webView2Args.NewWindow = webView2.CoreWebView2;
        _webView2Deferral.Complete();
    }

    webView2.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDefaultContextMenusEnabled = false;
    webView2.CoreWebView2.Settings.AreDevToolsEnabled = false;

    webView2.CoreWebView2.ContextMenuRequested += CoreWebView2_ContextMenuRequested;
    webView2.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
}

private void CoreWebView2_ContextMenuRequested(object? sender, CoreWebView2ContextMenuRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true; // set to true to prevent the default right-click menu from displaying
    e.MenuItems.Clear(); // remove all right-click menu items 
}

private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object? sender, CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    _webView2Args = e;
    _webView2Deferral = e.GetDeferral();
}

private void ButtonPrint_Click(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintNowAsync();
}

private async Task PrintNowAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // This prompts the user with a dialog box before printing.
     webView2.CoreWebView2.ShowPrintUI(CoreWebView2PrintDialogKind.System);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use SumatraPDF from a shell as you structured it above.

SumatraPdf is third-party, but it's free and open source.

- [SumatraPdf at GitHub](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf)
- [SumatraPdf Command Line Parameters](https://gitlab.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/-/wikis/Command-line-arguments)

  ```
    using (var p = new Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = @".\SumatraPDF.exe",
            Arguments = $"-print-settings {printSettings} -print-to \"{printerName}\" \"{filePath}\"",
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
        };

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the updated link. It does not look like any of the print options changed. Also, thanks for the information about the print limitations. I didn't see any of that in the documentation and have been using this as a solution without any problems. It should work with most desktop and network printers, but I've never tried it on specialized printers (aka thermal, etc.) as you mentioned.

Comment: Also, Sumatra PDF is free to distribute, but if you have commercial software, Artifex GhostScript requires you to either make the source code for your application publicly available or purchase a recurring commercial license. (The price was not available on their web site. You had to contact them for pricing.) See: https://artifex.com/licensing/commercial/